# Pass Flask app properties to Flask blueprint with Jinja template

Tags: python, flask

I am having bigger Flask app and I want to utilize blueprints for cleaner design. Current code looks like this:

`main_app.py`:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
# ... some config passing to app ...
app.register_blueprint(user_management, url_prefix="/user")
```

and `user_management.py`

```
user_management = Blueprint("user_management", __name__, static_folder="static", template_folder="templates")

@user_management.route("/register")
def register_user():
    register_form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render_template('user_registration.html', title="...", form=register_form)
```

The problem I am currently trying to solve is that I have base Jinja template `layout.html`, which is used in blueprints Jinja template `user_registration.html` like this:

```
{# user_registration.html #}
{% extends "layout.html" %}
```

But the `layout.html` is using some global variables of Flask `app` via `flask.g` and also config of `app`. When I try to load page with `user_registration.html` template (`/user/register`), it prints out error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'ac' is undefined
```

The `ac` variable is defined inside of another route in `main_app.py` like `g.ac = "..."`. I managed to solve this by adding parameter to template rendering inside of `register_user()` method as `render_template(..., ac=g.ac)`, but it is not really elegant way of solving this issue, because there are also some other variables like config of `app` (also used in `layout.html`), which brings another error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'flask.config.Config object' has no attribute 'login'
```

There must be some better way of handling this issue and passing base `app` attributes and global variables from `flask.g` inside of blueprint Jinja template. I've read multiple threads but cannot find similar issue.

Comment: You could create a context dictionary and pass it into the template as a single argument. This context dict can hold all the global values and the app instance specific things. You can use the flask.current_app inside your view funtions to access the current flask application instance.

Comment: I thought about this solution, but I did not really like it, because you pass all global variales and app variables, where many of them may be unused. But I guess I may be just overthinking the problem and it is not that big of a deal. Thank you for your answer.